# Cannot set high resolution in Intel UHD graphics

Tags: 18.04, laptop, intel-graphics, hp, display-resolution

I cannot set the screen resolution on my new HP [15s-fq1013ns](https://www.amazon.es/dp/B07Z3Q8341) Laptop with i3 10th generation chipset with Intel UHD Graphics and Ubuntu 18.04.   I tried several of the answers in this forum but they have all failed with basically the same error, which can be seen at the end of this terminal screen capture:

```
>> sudo su

>> lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a56 (rev 07)

>> xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 

>> xrandr --listactivemonitors
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Monitors: 1
 0: +*default 1024/271x768/203+0+0  default

>> cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync

>> xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

>> xrandr --addmode default "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

>> xrandr --output default --mode "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1024x768 (desired size 1920x1080)

>>
```

Though the last command actually activating the new mode fails, the new resolution is available in the dropdown for resolution on the display settings of the system configuration, but setting it fails as well.  The screen test shows up, but it shows the unchanged low screen resolution, so I reject the change.

I tried creating an `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file with the parameters provided by cvt, but that also fails. I am not sure the `xorg.conf` file is still used, different sources here say different things, but I guessed I might as well try.

The screen works wonderfully in Windows 10 (I had it set up in dual boot) and I noticed something interesting. When booting, it starts in low resolution, then the screen blinks and the logo shown at boot time gets smaller and moves to up and left, as if the resolution gets changed and the image is not scaled for the new setting.  This makes me think the graphics chip starts in low res and at some point during boot time the higher resolution becomes available.  This is just the splash screen so it is well before the full Windows becomes alive.

I did install the drivers from `oibaf/graphics-drivers` but that made little difference.

In the end, by whatever means I tried, it seems it all ends up causing the same error, whether it shows it or fails silently:

```
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 1024x768 (desired size 1920x1080)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: For testing purposes only: 1) Does this occur when you boot with a Kubuntu 19.10 LiveUSB created from the ISO at kubuntu.org ? 2) What is the model of the HP  laptop in question? Please collect that from the sticker which also has the serial number, and then click [edit] to add that information into the original question. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].

Answer (score 0):

As per [K7AAY](https://askubuntu.com/users/197910/k7aay) I tried Ubuntu 19.10 via a bootable USB stick and it worked right out of the box.  I'm in the process of updating my installation from 18.04 as shown [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes?_ga=2.58382569.2135439708.1575462899-267662915.1575124635#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_19.04)  (it also applies to upgrading from 18.04 to 19.04 and ultimately to 19.10)

Thanks for the help